# I can't save the last play date and can't compare last play date with current date

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all hi to all of you. I am trying to save last play date with current date in my unity game. If they are not equal i am going to fill up trial count. I am fetching the date from internet so players can't cheat in game with doing date changing in phone. I can bring the date and can see it in console. I am saving the that date after comparing date. Saving same variable with console debug variable but this thing can't save it. Please help... Here is my code.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener

{

    public int maxPlayCount = 5;
    public int currentPlayCount;
    public int dailyReward = 5;
    public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI playCountText;
    public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI rewardText;

    private DateTime lastPlayDate;
    private DateTime dateTime;
    private DateTime timeData;
    private string apiEndpoint = "https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Istanbul";
    private string dateTimeStr;
    private string lastPlayDateStr;
    private bool isAdAvailable = false;

    string _adUnitId = null;

    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOSAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";

    [Serializable]
    public class TimeData
    {
        public int year;
        public int month;
        public int day;
        public int hour;
        public int minute;
        public int seconds;
        public int milliSeconds;
        public string dateTime;
        public string date;
        public string time;
        public string timeZone;
        public string dayOfWeek;
        public bool dstActive;
    }
    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
        _adUnitId = _iOSAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        _adUnitId = _androidAdUnitId;
#endif
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Tarih bilgisini güncelliyoruz.
        StartCoroutine(GetCurrentTime());

        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("LastPlayDateStr"))
        {
            // İlk kez oyun açıldığında tarih bilgisini kaydediyoruz.
            SavePlayDate();
        }
        else
        {
            // Daha önce kaydedilen son oynama tarihini alıyoruz.
            string lastPlayDateStr = PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastPlayDateStr");
            Debug.Log("Son Oynama Tarihi: " + lastPlayDateStr);
            if (lastPlayDateStr == dateTimeStr)
            {
                // Son oynama tarihi bugün ise, mevcut oynama hakkını yüklüyoruz.
                currentPlayCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentPlayCount");
                Debug.Log("Son oynama tarihi bugün. Mevcut oynama hakkı yüklendi.");
            }
            else
            {
                //Son oynama tarihi bugün değil ise oynama hakkını güncelliyoruz.
                currentPlayCount = maxPlayCount;
                SavePlayDate();
                Debug.Log("Son oynama tarihi bugün değil. Oynama hakkı güncellendi.");

            }
        }



        UpdateUI();
    }

    IEnumerator GetCurrentTime()
    {
        // Tarih bilgisini almak için sunucuya bağlantı isteği gönderiyoruz.
        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(apiEndpoint);
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
            {
                // Sunucudan gelen tarih bilgisini alıyoruz.
                string jsonResult = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
                TimeData timeData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TimeData>(jsonResult);
                string dateTimeStr = timeData.date;
                Debug.Log("Bugünün tarihi: " + dateTimeStr);
            }
            else
            {

                Debug.Log("Error while fetching date from server: " + webRequest.error);
                yield break;
            }



        }
    }

    void SavePlayDate()
    {
        // Son oynama tarihini kaydediyoruz.
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastPlayDateStr", dateTimeStr);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentPlayCount", maxPlayCount);
        currentPlayCount = maxPlayCount;
        UpdateUI();
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        // UI elemanlarını güncelliyoruz.
        playCountText.text = "Kalan Enerji: " + currentPlayCount;
        rewardText.text = "Ödül: " + dailyReward;
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        if (currentPlayCount > 0)
        {
            currentPlayCount--;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentPlayCount", currentPlayCount);
            UpdateUI();
            Debug.Log("Starting game...");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("You have no play count left. Watch an ad to get a play count.");
            ShowAd();
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string _adUnitId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad loaded: " + _adUnitId);
        isAdAvailable = true;
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string _adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Ad failed to load: " + _adUnitId + " - Error: " + error.ToString() + " - Message: " + message);
        isAdAvailable = false;
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string _adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Ad failed to show: " + _adUnitId + " - Error: " + error.ToString() + " - Message: " + message);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string _adUnitId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad started: " + _adUnitId);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string _adUnitId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad clicked: " + _adUnitId);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string _adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad completed: " + _adUnitId + " - Completion state: " + showCompletionState.ToString());

        // Reklam kapatıldıktan sonra oynama hakkını yüklüyoruz.
        currentPlayCount++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentPlayCount", currentPlayCount);
        UpdateUI();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Ad error: " + message);
    }


    public void ShowAd()
    {
        // Reklam göstermek için uygun mu diye kontrol ediyoruz.
        if (isAdAvailable)
        {
            // Reklamı gösteriyoruz ve uygun listener'ları atıyoruz.
            Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
            isAdAvailable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Reklam yüklenmediyse yeniden yüklüyoruz.
            Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
        }
    }



    public void OnAdClosed()
    {
        // Reklam kapatıldıktan sonra oynama hakkını yüklüyoruz.

        UpdateUI();
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }


}
```

I tried to make everything string and it didn't work. Also tried making everything DateTime it is started to cover all console with error messages.

Comment: My initial guess after looking at your code is that you assuming that `StartCoroutine(GetCurrentTime());` synchronous operation but it is not, is happening in parallel so by the moment you are asking if the PlayerPrefs key exist it has finished fetching the data you want, I'll recommend you either moving your  `SavePlayDate()` function inside the coroutine or have a variable to track the state of the coroutine so once it finishes you can use the result accordingly

Comment: As said already `StartCoroutine(GetCurrentTime())` finishing long after your `Start` method continued with all the rest! It will not delay the code around it. Also in there you have a local variable `dateTimeStr` .. you never assign your class field with the same name

Comment: In your check for the [`UnityWebRequest.result`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Result.html) you also don't cover all cases btw ;) it would be way easier to rather check for `result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success`

Comment: Note that `Start` itself can be a routine so you could simply use `private IEnumerator Start () { yield return GetCurrentTime(); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are not waiting until your webRequest finishes but directly continue to check the values.

There are multiple other issus such as e.g. inside the `GetCurrentTime` you have

```
string dateTimeStr = timeData.date;
```

so your class field with he same name is **never assigned**.

You can btw directly make your `Start` itself be a coroutine and do e.g.

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return GetCurrentTime();
    
    ...
}
```

and then also make sure you assign your class fields

```
IEnumerator GetCurrentTime()
{
    ...

    // Note: your check also didn't cover all potential cases
    if(webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        ...

        dateTimeStr = timeData.date;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```